# Virtual Box BSOD SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, bsod, crash

Every time I run Virtual Box I get a BSOD saying SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION. I've never *sucessully* ran Virtual Box on my computer before, and I have all drivers installed, thanks to iobit Driver Booster, and things should be stable thanks to iobit Advanced System Care.
Technical Information:

`STOP: 0x0000003B (0x00000000C0000005,0xFFFF88003E485EE,0xFFFFF88008F62D60,0x0000000000000000)
asmtxhci.sys Address FFFFF88003E485EE base at FFFFF88003E2A00, DateStamp 56b2f7ed`

Running on Windows 7 64 Bit, with 16gb of RAM.
I've spent more than plenty of time on Google, and found nothing more than a few tickets on it, and a few pages in Russian. Great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run windbg to determine the cause

Comment: The `asmtxhci.sys` that's causing the crash is an [XHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXtensible_Host_Controller_Interface_%28xHCI%29) driver by [ASMedia Technology Inc.](http://www.asmedia.com.tw/). Try updating that driver (`mmc devmgmt.msc` and look for those or USB 3.0). You can also try switching from the USB 3.0 (xHCI) in your virtual machine settings under the USB settings to USB 2.0 (EHCI) or 1.0 (OCHI) ..

Comment: http://www.drivermax.com/driver/device.php?id=PCI%2BVEN_1B21%26DEV_1042%26SUBSYS_84881043%26REV_00%2B6.1%2B64&driver=ASMedia+XHCI+Controller Thanks for the response, after installing the driver from the link i found, and a reinstall of Virtual Box, the problem is solved.